# Authenticate two different devise classes in same controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have this view called Intranet where only authenticated "devise clients" can access.

```
class IntranetController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_client!
  def index
  end
end
```

On the other side, I also have other "devise admin", this devise admin requires to access the same view. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612545/devise-login-with-user-or-admin-models-and-basecamp-style-subdomains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class IntranetController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_all! 
  def index 
  end
  def authenticate_all! 
     if admin_signed_in? 
       true
     else 
       authenticate_client! 
     end 
  end
end
```