# Tests failing with undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, minitest

I searched about the error and got various solutions for Rspec.
I am using Minitest and could not understand how to implement it in Minitest.

From what I understand, I am supposed to sign-in the user in "test_helper.rb" by calling `include Devise::TestHelpers`

I am using
Ruby 2.1.1p76
Rails 4.2.5.1
Rake 11.1.2
Minitest

I am getting the following error:

```
LocationsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
    app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb:41:in `_app_views_layouts__navbar_html_erb__1573266900144599421_47382981019560'
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1642478743058061304_47382980397060'
    test/controllers/locations_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:LocationsControllerTest>'
```

_navbar.html.erb:41

```
<% if current_user %>
```

test_helpers.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

test/controllers/locations_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class LocationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @location = locations(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:locations)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create location" do
    assert_difference('Location.count') do
      post :create, location: { long_name: @location.long_name, short_name: @location.short_name }
    end

    assert_redirected_to location_path(assigns(:location))
  end

  test "should show location" do
    get :show, id: @location
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @location
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update location" do
    patch :update, id: @location, location: { long_name: @location.long_name, short_name: @location.short_name }
    assert_redirected_to location_path(assigns(:location))
  end

  test "should destroy location" do
    assert_difference('Location.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @location
    end

    assert_redirected_to locations_path
  end
end
```

test/fixtures/users.yml

```
one:
  email: user_email@som.com
  encrypted_password: abc
  sign_in_count: 2
  current_sign_in_at: Time.now
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to add a call to the Devise minitest helpers in your `test_helper.rb`

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
end
```

Or if you have an older version of Devise:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

You then need to add a call to `sign_in` before each test where a user should be signed in. In your example, change the setup to:

```
setup do
  sign_in users(:one)
  @location = locations(:one)
end
```

As @Iceman points out, this is [documented in the Devise README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers).

Comment: The most up-to-date method is to include `include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers`

Comment: @ReggieB I was able to sign in the user but not the admin user. So, the pages where I require admin to sign in are redirecting me to the login page asserting 302 instead of success.

Comment: @KartikeyTanna How are you defining admin users? Is there an Admin or AdminUser model, or are some Users admins?

Comment: I am doing it through AdminUser module.

Comment: @ReggieB The code is here in the last commits if you can take a look https://github.com/tannakartikey/currents/commits/develop

Comment: Yes the behaviour is correct. Your Buzz controller only has `before_action :authenticate_user!` and no user is logged in - only an admin user. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612545/devise-login-with-user-or-admin-models-and-basecamp-style-subdomains

Comment: @ReggieB Okay. But how do I get admin_user logged in while running tests? Because of my Admin user is not logged in my tests are failing with redirection. I want the tests to login as Admin and perform the actions.

Comment: It looks to me like `admin_user` is logged in for your tests. The problem isn't the tests - if you want an admin user to access those pages you will need to update your controller code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136349/discussion-between-kartikey-tanna-and-reggieb).